# Python imports, utils file and how to combine them

Tags: python, import, python-import

In our project there is a `utils.py` file that provides functions for several files (DRY).

Needless to say how this is done, but I will note in case it is not understood, 
in those files we do `import utils` and use the necessary functions.

During development one of our developers uploaded a PR in which he added serveral functions to the `utils.py` file, this is one of them:

```
list_dir(directory):
    return os.listdir(directory)
```

When we asked him why he wrote this function (just `import os` in the file you need, and use `os.listdir`)

He said:

1. He needed this functionality in several files
2. Why would he make the code ugly with `import os` in those files (then more `imports` for every one-line use of external module ,then you have thousand of `imports` in the top of the file)
3. `import utils` **already exists in those files**.
4. Moreover, `import os` **already exists in the `utils.py` file**.

Needless to say, we all know that Python makes a one-time import for modules, the question here is different:

What is more called Pythonic ? When there is a one-line (maybe two) function, just import the module into the file that needs the function (though it looks like the code gets ugly), or write it in `utils.py`. ?

Comment: `list_dir(directory):
    os.listdir(directory)` doesn't add any value, and since it's not returning anything, it's not even useful

Comment: If it would return value or bundle couple of operations it would make sense. But for saving lines of import, define the structure of your project with base lib.

Comment: @Vinny Can you explain: "define the structure of your project with base lib".

Comment: @SpazaM let's say you need to check and create directory if non-existed in many places in your code. defining such a function which checks if the directory exist and create's it otherwise in a `utils.py` module has benefit. Keep it as abstract as possible, and you would be able to use it in many places in your project instead of rewriting it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is more called Pythonic?

The usual practice is to just import modules in the places where you need them.  That would mean writing "import os" in every module where it is used.

There is legitimate reason I can think of.  If in the future, you need to change what *list_dir()* does (perhaps filtering-out certain categories of files), it is nice to have all the users referencing the same source.

One other thought.  As currently written, there is no need to have a wrapper function at all.  In `utils.py` just write `from os import listdir as list_dir`.

Also, why change the name at all?  Minimize complexity by sticking with *listdir*.

Comment: Thank you Raymond, more than excited to hear your opinion.